# Why is my ggplot generating phantom data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-text, ggrepel

My plot seems to be inserting data not in my df.
Code for my plot:

```
X <- ggplot(methods_per_CONSM_majors |> mutate(Majors = factor(Majors) |> fct_inorder(),
                    Measures = factor(Measures) |> fct_rev()), 
       aes(Majors, Measures, label = LCOs, color = Years)) + geom_text(size = 2.5) + geom_text_repel(box.padding = 1, max.overlaps = 5) +
  scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 8)) +
  labs(title = "TEMP:",
         subtitle = "TEMP") +
  xlab(label = "") +
  ylab(label = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(
      size = (0.1), colour =
        "lightgrey")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  geom_text_repel()

X + labs(color=NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("gold3", "firebrick2", "blue", 'orchid', 'black'))
```

Here's the problem: `Engineering` (for example) has one datapoint in `Rubric` and it is `2.1`. But when I plot, `2.1` appears *three times* for `Engineering`:

[[image]]

I realize the plot isn't actually inserting data into my df, but what is causing the appearance of these additional, phantom data labels?

---

## Data

```r
methods_per_CONSM_majors <- data.frame(
  'Majors'=c('Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 
             'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 
             'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Science (Pre-Nursing)', 'Engineering', 
             'Engineering', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 
             'Biology', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 
             'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 'Cell Biology', 
             'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 
             'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology', 'Macrobiology',  'Computer Information Science',  
             'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science',  
             'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science',  
             'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science',  'Computer Information Science', 
             'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 
             'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Science', 
             'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 
             'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 
             'Environmental Science', 'Environmental Science', 'Health Sciences', 'Health Sciences', 'Health Sciences', 
             'Health Sciences', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 
             'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Kinesiology', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 
             'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 
             'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 
             'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics',  
             'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 
             'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 
             'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences', 'Natural Sciences'), 
  'Measures'=c('Research Project/Essay', 
               'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Pre/Post', 'Ill-Defined', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 
               'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Exit Exam', 'Pre/Post', 'Quiz', 'Pre/Post', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Exit Exam', 
               'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exit Exam', 'Pre/Post', 'Quiz', 'Pre/Post', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 
               'Exit Exam', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exit Exam', 'Pre/Post', 'Quiz', 'Pre/Post', 'Pre/Post', 
               'Rubric', 'Exit Exam', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 
               'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Evaluator Observation/ Assessment', 'Evaluator Observation/ Assessment', 
               'Rubric', 'Exams & Projects', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Evaluator Observation/ Assessment', 
               'Evaluator Observation/ Assessment', 'Observation/ Other', 'Ill-Defined', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric',
               'Rubric', 'Exams (Multiple)', 'Rubric', 'Exams (Multiple)', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Exam',
               'Pre/Post', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Pre/Post', 'Rubric',
               'Exam', 'Ill-Defined', 'Exam', 'Exam', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Alumni Survey', 
               'Journal/ Reflection', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Exam', 'Exam', 'Exam', 
               'Exam', 'Exam', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Ill-Defined', 'Ill-Defined', 'Rubric', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 
               'Quiz', 'Quiz', 'Rubric', 'Exam', 'Exam', 'Quiz', 'Rubric'), 
  'LCOs'=c('1.1', '2.1', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', 
           '3.1', '2.1', '3.1', '1.2', '3.1', '2.1', '2.2', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', '2.1', '1.2', '2.2', '1.1', '2.1', 
           '2.2', '3.2', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', '2.1', '1.2', '2.2', '1.1', '2.1', '2.2', '3.2', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', 
           '2.1', '1.2', '2.2', '1.1', '2.1', '2.2', '3.2', '2', '4', '1.1', '3.1', '2.2', '4.2', '2.1', '4.1', '3.1', 
           '4.2', '2', '4', '1.1', '3.1', '1.1', '2.2', '2.1', '4.1', '3.1', '4.2', '1.2', '3.1', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', 
           '2.1', '1.2', '2.1', '1.2', '2.1', '1.1', '2.1', '1.2', '2.2', '2.2', '5.1', '1.1', '5.1', '3.1', '6.1', '4.1', 
           '7.1', '2.1', '5.1', '3.1', '4.1', '4.2', '3.2', '3.3', '5.1', '5.3', '5.2', '1.1', '1.2', '5.3', '5.2', '5.1', 
           '2.1', '2.2', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '4.1', '4.2', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '4.1', '4.2', '2.1', 
           '3.6', '3.1', '4.1', '1.1', '2.1', '3', '5'), 
  'Years'=c('2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', 
            '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', 
            '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', 
            '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', 
            '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', 
            '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2017-2018', '2017-2018', 
            '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', 
            '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', 
            '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', 
            '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', 
            '2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', 
            '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2017-2018',  '2017-2018',  '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2018-2019',
            '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', 
            '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', '2021-2022', 
            '2021-2022', '2017-2018', '2017-2018',  '2017-2018', '2017-2018',  '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2018-2019', 
            '2019-2020', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2021-2022', '2021-2022'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I presume it's `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`, I see you use it twice, is that the problem? (plus maybe you have a `geom_text` in your example screenshot)

Comment: Agree with Jon. You have two `geom_text_repel` layers + a `geom_text`. Hence you end up with three labels for each data point.

Comment: You also have two `scale_y_discrete`.

Comment: Thanks @stefan. How do I prevent `geom_text_repel()` from adding a second label at a single datapoint? E.g., there should be a '3.1' at Science (Pre-Nursing)+Ill-Defined. But geom_text_repel() adds an unnecessary label. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in the posted code.
The main error is to have repeated layers, `geom_text_repel` and `scale_y_discrete`. There are also repeated `labs`, `x/ylabs` and `theme`'s.
And the data transformations are made before the plot, not in the `data` argument.

In the code below I start by defining a custom `theme`, so that the plot that follows is simpler and more readable.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(forcats)
  library(stringr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggrepel)
})

theme_so_q77248246 <- function() {
  theme_minimal() %+replace%    #
    theme(
      panel.grid = element_line(linewidth = 0.1, colour = "lightgrey"),
      legend.position = "top",
      axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5, color = "black")
    )
}

methods_per_CONSM_majors |> 
  mutate(Majors = factor(Majors) |> fct_inorder(),
         Measures = factor(Measures) |> fct_rev()) |>
  ggplot(aes(Majors, Measures, label = LCOs, color = Years)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0) + 
  geom_text(size = 2.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(box.padding = 1, max.overlaps = 5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)) +
  labs(title = "TEMP:", subtitle = "TEMP", x = "", y = "") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(
    nrow = 1, 
    override.aes = list(alpha = 1, size = 5)
  )) +
  theme_so_q77248246() -> X

X + labs(color = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("gold3", "firebrick2", "blue", 'orchid', 'black'))
#> Warning: ggrepel: 117 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider
#> increasing max.overlaps
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>